# Specific table alignment issue

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is a generalized version of my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style="font-size: 36px">
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body style="min-width:100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

                <div align="center">
<table align="center" width="720" height="3653" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="720" valign="top" colspan="14">

                <img src="" width="720" height="207" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" valign="top" colspan="14">

                <img src="" width="720" height="373" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" height="152" valign="top" colspan="14" style="background-color:black">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:36pt;"><br><center>
              <p style="color:white"><strong>Statement<br> 
                </strong></p></span> 
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:30pt;">  
              <p style="color:white">Statement</p>
<span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:30pt;">  
            <h5 style="color:white">Statement</h5>
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:24pt;">  
              <p style="color:white">Statement</p>
      </center></span></td></p>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="720" height="547" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <p align="center"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:35pt;"><strong>Statement<br></strong></span><br><br><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:22pt;">Statement<br></span></p><p align="center">Site</p>
            <tr>
                    <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:20pt;"><center><b><p>Statement</p>

<tr>
        <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:20pt;"><center><b><p>Statement</p>


    </tr>
<br> 
<tr>
        <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:20pt;"><center><b><p>Site </p>
              <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:20pt;"><center><b><p>Statement</p>
            <hr width="60%"></b></center></span></td>
    </tr>
                </strong></p></span>

    </tr>
<tr>
        <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:20pt;"><center><b><p>Date</p>

    <tr>
        <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:26pt;"><center><b><p>Statement</p>

            <hr width="60%"></b></center></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:20pt;"><center><b><p>Date</p>

    <tr>
        <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:26pt;"><center><b><p>Statement</p>

            <hr width="60%"></b></center></span></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:20pt;"><center><b><p>Statement</p>

    <tr>
        <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:26pt;"><center><b><p>Statement
</p>

            <hr width="60%"></b></center></span></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:20pt;"><center><b><p>Date</p>

    <tr>
        <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:26pt;"><center><b><p>Statement
</p>

            <hr width="60%"></b></center></span></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="720" height="34" valign="top" colspan="14" style="padding-right:55px; padding-left:55px;">
            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:20pt;"><center><b><p>Statement
</p>
             <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:14pt;"><center><b><p>Statement

</p>

            <hr width="60%"></b></center></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" valign="top" colspan="14">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="720" height="226" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="15" valign="top" rowspan="3">
            <img src="" width="15" height="600" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td width="160" valign="top" colspan="2" rowspan="3">
            <a href=""><img src="" width="160" height="600" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
        <td width="18" valign="top" colspan="2" rowspan="3">
            <img src="" width="18" height="600" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td width="336" valign="top" colspan="5">
            <a href=""><img src="" width="336" height="280" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
        <td width="18" valign="top" rowspan="3">
            <img src="" width="18" height="600" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td width="160" valign="top" colspan="2" rowspan="3">
            <a href=""><img src="" width="160" height="600" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
        <td width="13" valign="top" rowspan="3">
            <img src="" width="13" height="600" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="336" valign="top" colspan="5">
            <img src="" width="336" height="40" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="336" valign="top" colspan="5">
            <a href=""><img src="" width="336" height="280" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" valign="top" colspan="14">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="720" height="176" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" valign="top" colspan="14">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="720" height="375" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" valign="top" colspan="14">
            <img src="" width="720" height="59" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" valign="top" colspan="14">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="720" height="105" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" valign="top" colspan="14">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="720" height="113" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" valign="top" colspan="14">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="720" height="111" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" valign="top" colspan="14">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="720" height="108" border="" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="85" valign="top" colspan="2">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="85" height="131" border="1" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
        <td width="85" valign="top" colspan="2">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="85" height="131" border="1" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
        <td width="85" valign="top" colspan="2">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="85" height="131" border="1" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
        <td width="85" valign="top" colspan="2">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="85" height="131" border="1" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
        <td width="85" valign="top" colspan="2">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="85" height="131" border="1" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
        <td width="85" valign="top" colspan="2">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="85" height="131" border="1" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
        <td width="85" valign="top" colspan="2">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="85" height="131" border="1" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
        <td width="125" valign="top" colspan="0">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="125" height="131" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" valign="top" colspan="14">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" width="720" height="63" border="0" style="display:block" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="15" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="75" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="85" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="5" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="13" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="77" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="76" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="76" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="76" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="31" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="18" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="32" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="128" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="" width="13" height="1" style="display:block" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div></body>
</html>
```

I am having trouble aligning everything within a width of 720. Specifically the black box in row three with the two images above, and the 8 icons at the bottom. I figured that since the 8th icon is a little wider setting its width to 125 and the other 7 to 85 would make a straight 720 across all the icons, but they don't match up:

As you can see from the screenshots below, everything is shifted to the left of a container that's larger than 720:

Photo1

[image]

Photo2

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you unfamiliar with `CSS`? This project may be much simpler for you if you code your styles through a separate file. Also, there may be little to no need to style everything as tables, either. You can use standard `<div>` elements, if I'm understanding your problem correctly. Here is a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5q3l.png) of the result of what I've made with the code I'll post below.

Here is my Code

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 1080px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
.box1 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 300px;
  width: 720px;
  margin: auto;
}
.box2 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 300px;
  width: 720px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.box2 p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.smallTable {
  width: 1080px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.smallBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: 85px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
.bigBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: 125px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="table">
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box2">
          <p>Statement</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="smallTable">
        <div class="smallBox"></div>
        <div class="smallBox"></div>
        <div class="smallBox"></div>
        <div class="smallBox"></div>
        <div class="smallBox"></div>
        <div class="smallBox"></div>
        <div class="smallBox"></div>
        <div class="bigBox"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I use styling rules like `margin: auto;` to move my `<div>` elements to the center of their parent element. The bottom eight boxes can be aligned the same way, using `display: inline-block;` to make them display horizontally.

I hope this answered your question to some degree. It doesn't make much sense to write so much in-line styling. Practice DRY programming whenever possible, and with tools like `CSS`, there isn't a reason to repeat so much styling.

Comment: This is what I eventually did (no table), but in your screenshot I noticed that the images don't align with the box, and the icons aren't contained perfectly within the constant width (images, box, all 8 icons).

Comment: I didn't account, nor adjust for, border lengths and padding between boxes. Those are configurable as well -- just wanted to show you a better way of setting up, and styling, your code.